# MATLAB for loop plots

Tags: matlab, graph, for-loop, plot

I have a quick question on making a simple plot in MATlab. I have done this before but for some reason it has stopped working, and the graph I want is no longer coming up.

I am not sure how much information is going to be needed in order for this question to be answered so please let me know if I should add more.

I have a system of ODE's and am using the following parameters in a loop as one of the variables.

```
A4bar = NaN;
for eta_p = 0.0:.1:7;
A3bar=x(size(t,1),3);
A4bar= [A4bar;A3bar];
hold on
plot(eta_p,A4bar,'-k','linewidth',1);
```

When I use the above code, my graph comes up with a bunch of plotted points that are not connected.

When I use my original code that worked in the past i used this.

```
A4bar = NaN;
for eta_p = 0.0:.1:7;
A3bar=x(size(t,1),3);
A4bar= [A4bar;A3bar];
place_holder_eta_p = 0:.1:7.1;
hold on
plot(place_holder_eta_p,A4bar,'-k','linewidth',1);
```

The error I get for my original code is that the vector's are not equal. I have tried setting the place_holder_eta_p to match with eta_p, and that didn't work. It used to work with just the above code, so I am not sure what is going on.

Any idea's or suggestions? Maybe more importantly, let me know if there is any additional information I should be providing.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please post a more complete example - at least include the whole for loop up until the 'end'.

Comment: What is it that you are expecting to happen in the first example that is not happening? In the second example, as you say `place_holder_eta_p` has a different length, so why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't need a for loop to do what you want to do.  In fact, it's because you are plotting each individual point as its own plot that you get unconnected points in your graph.  In any case, you haven't shown how the changing variable `eta_p` is used within the loop.

The basic structure of what your code should look like is this:

```
eta_p = 0:0.1:7;
N     = length(eta_p);
A4bar = Zeros(1, N);       % same length as eta_p
% set up your other variables

% calculate the values in A4bar
% it might look like
% for i = 1:length(eta_p)
%     A4bar(i) = interesting_function(eta_p(i), A3bar, x, t);
% end

plot(eta_p, A4bar, '-k', 'linewidth', 1);
```

I don't know how to set up your other variables `A3bar`, `x`, `t`, and I can't tell what you need in that middle section to calculate the values of `A4bar` without any additional information.

The important things to note are

1. `eta_p` and `A4bar` are both size `[1 N]` (required for `plot` command)
2. The `plot` command happens once *outside* any loop, not inside it, and after you've calculated *all* the values of `A4bar`.

Comment: +1. Note that if your for loop is very slow and you want to see the progress of your calculation (see points come in one after the other), you *can* have the `plot` inside your loop. Just start with `eta_P` and `A4bar` both [1 N] arrays of NaNs and then progressively fill them with data. Make sure *not* to use `hold all` or `hold on` for your figure, then `plot` always replaces the previous plot. You also need to add `drawnow` after plot inside the loop to actually see anything...

Comment: Further to @Jonas comment, you can in fact update the existing plot rather than replace it using `set(h, 'XDataSource', 'eta_p', 'YDataSource', 'A4bar');` and then calling `refreshdata(h);` whenever you have updated `A4bar`.  The variable `h = plot(eta_p, A4bar, '-k', 'linewidth', 1);` in this case should be called before starting the loop that calculates `A4bar`.  This is faster than making a new plot if N is very large (though it isn't too large in this case).

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's help, especially to @Brian L. I really appreciate the time you spent on this to help me